# Batch converting in imagemagic

Tags: batch, imagemagick

I am trying to convert files in imagemagic 6.8.9 on linux . I am restoring an old video and have each frame written as a png file . SOme of these files I have to batch convert to give them an offset -1-4 with the following command to "move" the image in the frame.

```
convert test.png -repage -1-4 -background black -flatten newtest.png
```

That command does what I need for a single file however I need to preserve the original file names, and do this for hundreds of files.

WHen I try to use wildcards only the last file is converted using the wildcard used in the command.